# Knowing the number of asterisks to use in method definitions in C?

Tags: c, pointers

For example:

```
void DeleteLastNode(NodeType **L)
```

If **L represents the address of the variable L, can it not be replaced by &L instead? Also, if I were to use *L or simply just L, would I not be able to change L's contents? If so, what's the difference of using *L and L, if L is a pointer to it anyways? Would I not be able to look at it's contents just by sending in L and using *L in the actual method?

I guess I'm still not too good with pointers.

Comment: Binky will help you for sure: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mnXkiAKbUPg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know one asterisk represents a normal pointer in C. For instance you can allocate memory and make the pointer point the that new allocated area. You can also point to variables in the stack like:

```
int x = 10;
int *p = &x;
```

But there are some situations where you want to pass a pointer to a function and make the function able to change the pointer to point to another address. Now we are not talking about change the contents of a variable through a pointer nor a memory pointed by it but literary change the pointer information (which is a mem. address) to point to another places. In this case we use a pointer to a pointer which is represented by double asterisk.

```
int x, y;
int *p;
int **pp;

pp = &p;  //pp points to pointer p
*pp = &x; //pp changes pointer p to point to variable x
*p = 10;  //p (now points to x) assigns value 10 to x
*pp = &y; //pp changes pointer p again assigning the address of y
*p = 20;  //p assigns 20 to y;
**pp = 25;// that's tricky, the first * give access to the address pointed by p (&y) the second changes the content of that address to 25. so now y ends with 25
```

In the end x = 10 and y = 25

Now looking particularly in you case, that function call looks like a function that will remove a node from a linked list. And this makes sense because you have an external pointer pointing to the head of the list. When you remove the last element your function must be able to change the pointer from the current address to null. You can do it using a global pointer or, as it seems in your case, passing the address of the head pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Let's clear some things up. Technically, L is a pointer to a pointer to a NodeType instance. However, the name of the function suggests a different interpretation: probably L is the address of a pointer to an array or a linked list of NodeType instances (you have to consult the documentation of the function to verify this).

If that is the case, then the function would typically be used like this:

```
NodeType *list = malloc (5 * sizeof(NodeType));
/* do something with the list, e.g. put entries into it */
DeleteLastNode (&list);  /* delete last node in list */
```

The function probably modifies the variable pointing to the array/list, that's why you have to pass the address of **list** to the function.

But to say anything specific, we need more information about DeleteLastNode ().

Answer (score 0):

No, not in C, asterisks in the function header could not be replaced with ampersands (`&`) in the function body instead. In C++ it is another matter though. People thought somewhat similar thoughts and added this functionality when they decided on features for C++.

Answer (score 0):

Something that may help understand

```
NodeType **L
```

means L is a pointer to pointer to NodeType object.

For example, if it is

```
NodeType *P
```

then P is a pointer to NodeType object, and if P is 0xE0101010, and each NodeType object is 80 bytes, then P + 1 will be 0xE0101060 (0xE0101010 plus 0x50 = 0xE0101060).

Then let's look at L, which a pointer to pointer to NodeType.  If we consider a pointer being 4 bytes, then if L is 0xE0202020, and L + 1 will be just 0xE0202024.

So it is important to use the right type, whenever pointer arithmetics is involved.  Note that L[3] is the same as *(L + 3), so L[3] involves pointer arithmetics, therefore the pointer types need to be very precise, or else when you look at the content of where a pointer is pointing to by *L, which is call dereferencing, then a segmentation fault (Unix/Linux) or GP fault (Windows) can occur.

Answer (score 0):

```
NodeType nt;
NodeType *pnt = &nt;

--------         ------
| pnt  |-------->| nt |
--------         ------
```

Here, `pnt` (content of `pnt`) is `&nt`; `*pnt` is `nt`.

```
NodeType **L = &pnt;

------        --------         ------
| L  |------->| pnt  |-------->| nt |
------        --------         ------
```

Now `L` (content of `L`) is `&pnt`; `*L` is `pnt`; and thus `**L` is `*pnt`, which is `nt`. Note that `*&` *cancels* each other (`*L -> *&pnt -> pnt`).

Answer (score 0):

> If **L represents the address of the variable L, can it not be replaced by &L instead?

`**L` represents the *value* at the location pointed to by the location pointed to by `L`.  For illustration, assume the following declarations:

```
int     a =   1;
int  * pa = & a; // whitespace doesn't matter here
int **ppa = &pa;
```

`ppa` points to `pa`, which in turn points to `a`, which has the value `1`.  Here's a hypothetical memory map showing their relationships (assume 32-bit ints, big-endian):

```
Object       Address        0x00  0x01  0x02  0x03
------       -------        ----------------------
     a       0x10008000     0x00  0x00  0x00  0x01
    pa       0x10008004     0x10  0x00  0x80  0x00 
   ppa       0x10008008     0x10  0x00  0x80  0x04
```

In a *declarator*, the `*` operator indicates that this variable is a *pointer* and holds the address of another variable.  In an *expression*, the `*` operator yields the value that the pointer points to.  In a **C++** *declarator*, the `&` operator indicates that this variable is a *reference* and is a *synonym* for another variable (which is not necessarily the same thing as a pointer; C does not allow the `&` in a declarator).  In an *expression*, the `&` operator yields the *address* of its operand.

So, going by the memory map above, all of the following are true:

```
    a == 1;
 * pa == 1; // again, whitespace doesn't matter here.
**ppa == 1; 

   &a == 0x10008000;
   pa == 0x10008000;
 *ppa == 0x10008000;

  &pa == 0x10008004;
  ppa == 0x10008004;

 &ppa == 0x10008008;
```